# Why is this grammar ambiguous?

Tags: formal-languages, programming-languages

```
S ::= x
S ::= if E then S
S ::= if E then S else S
```

This is example `if E then if E then x else x` proves that it is ambiguous but I don't see why? Isn't it just an if statement within an if statement.

Comment: The `else` could be part of either `if`, according to the grammar. Search for "dangling else".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rici is correct.  The statement could be reasonably interpreted, as you first assumed:

```
if E then ( if E then x ) else x
```

It may also be interpreted:

```
if E then ( if E then x else x )
```

In a context-free grammar, the allowable set of expressions are determined through substitution.  In the first interpretation I took your third statement and substituted the first S for the second statement, and then replaced all remain S with x.  In the second interpretation, I took your second statement and replaced it with the third statement, and replaced the remaining S with x using the first statement.